# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, dom-events

```
 function Sidebar({ items, depthStep, depth, expanded }) {
  82 |   return (
  83 |     <div className="sidebar">
> 84 |       <List disablePadding dense>
  85 |         
  86 |         {items.map((sidebarItem, index) => (
  87 |           <React.Fragment key={`${sidebarItem.name}${index}`}>
```

Comment: Whatever component is rendering Sidebar is not passing `items` or is passing a value of `undefined`. Trying map on undefined `undefined.map()` will give you this error.

Comment: Can you show where items is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `items` is unavoidably passed to `Sidebar` as null or undefined, you could conditionally call map instead:

```
{
    items ? 
        items.map((sidebarItem, index) => (
            <React.Fragment key={`${sidebarItem.name}${index}`}>
        )
    : null
}
```